# Babel error when running ./gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I receive this error after running `./gradlew assembleRelease`:

```
    Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
 In C:\..\node_modules\babel-preset-expo\index.js

    :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

    **FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**
```

This is what I have in **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "Mascota24",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-circle-checkbox": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^6.4.0",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.7",
    "react-navigation": "^2.6.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

And this is **.babelrc** file:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}
```

I've followed almost every post here related with this and none of them helped me :( Thanks for any help

Comment: Add you error please

Comment: @ashutoshpandey the error is: "Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
 In C:\..\node_modules\babel-preset-expo\index.js

    :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

    **FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**"

Comment: let me check now

Comment: did you run any update command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210574/create-react-native-app-plugin-preset-files-are-not-allowed-to-export-objects
Check this link aroudn

Comment: i run "npm update" as part of the possible solutions i found, but before that it wasn't working neither...

Comment: can you check above link

Comment: i checked, i changed  the version to "react-native": "^0.55" but still the same :(

Comment: wait.., the error changed, now it's "Unable to resolve module `redux` from `C:\Users\Digital\Mascota24\store.js`: Module `redux` does not exist in the Haste module map"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174906/discussion-between-ashutosh-pandey-and-guille).

Comment: Look in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210574/create-react-native-app-plugin-preset-files-are-not-allowed-to-export-objects
Check this link it work for you .

Comment: Look in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210574/create-react-native-app-plugin-preset-files-are-not-allowed-to-export-objects
Check this link it work for you .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ashutosh pandey for the help, I changed `react-native` version to:

```
"react-native": "^0.55"
```

Then I installed `redux` and could generate the .apk! :D

Comment: @ashutoshpandey can you chat 1 sec?

Comment: yeap. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330836/react-native-router-not-working