# react native router not working

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I need to display the same page (Login) when the user id is incorrect. For this when i receive the error from the API I display a message and a link to go back to Login page, this link is not doing anything.

Login.js

```
render() {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const resp = navigation.getParam("resp", "NO-resp");

  if (resp == "dni_incorrecto") {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.welcomeMsg}>
          <Text style={styles.dni_incorrecto}>
            El DNI ingresado es incorrecto.
          </Text>
          <NativeRouter>
            <View>
              <View>
                <Link to="/Login">
                  <Text>Public Page</Text>
                </Link>
              </View>

              <Route
                path="/Login"
                render={() => (
                  <Login navigation={navigation} dni={""} resp="" />
                )}
              />
            </View>
          </NativeRouter>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The API response renders a component that navigate back to Login page using:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Login', { resp:'dni_incorrecto'});
```

Comment: just a second , i will reply you .

Comment: @Guile did you find my answer  helpfull

Comment: thanks, i could resolve this using the router. now i have this issue :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365912/flatlist-renderitem-is-called-multiple-times

Answer (score 0):

popToTop() - Pop to the first scene in the stack, unmounting every other scene
You can use this it will redirect you to first page you have used in your screen .

```
This.props.naviagtion.popToTop
```

Let me know if it won't work.

Comment: i had to change to react router, but i'm having issues too. When i link to a component it renders it but over the previous component: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352844/react-router-native-renders-linked-component-over-previous-one

Comment: Finally i could resolve it using the router. Now i'm having an issue with FlatList: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365912/flatlist-renderitem-is-called-multiple-times