# react router native renders linked component over previous one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

When i link to a component this renders but over the existing component.
It doesn't "navigate", the view is not being replaced with the linked one.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  AppRegistry,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,    
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native'
import styles from './LoginStyleSheet';
import CircleCheckBox , {LABEL_POSITION} from 'react-native-circle-checkbox';
import SocialFooter from './SocialFooter';
import { NativeRouter, Route, Link, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-native'
import TelUtiles from './TelUtiles';
//const { navigation } = this.props;
//const resp = navigation.getParam('resp', 'NO-resp');

const AuthExample = () => (

  <NativeRouter>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container_logo}>
        <Image source={require('./img/logo-main.png')} style={styles.logo_img} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.welcomeMsg}>                                                         
        <Text 
            style={styles.welcomeMsg_textTop}>
            ¡Bienvenido a nuestra 
        </Text>
        <Text 
            style={styles.welcomeMsg_textBottom}>
            familia mascotera!
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.container_input_dni}>
            <TextInput placeholder='DNI:' placeholderTextColor="#E3A141" underlineColorAndroid="#E3A141" style={styles.input_dni} />                        
        </View>
        <Link
          to="/protected"
          style={styles.navItem_login}
          underlayColor='#f0f4f7'>
            <Text style={styles.navItem_login_text}>Protected Page</Text>
        </Link>
      </View>
      <AuthButton/>
      <View style={styles.nav}>
        <Link
          to="/public"
          style={styles.navItem}
          underlayColor='#f0f4f7'>
            <Text>Public Page</Text>
        </Link>
        <Link
          to="/protected"
          style={styles.navItem}
          underlayColor='#f0f4f7'>
            <Text>Protected Page</Text>
        </Link>
        <Link
            to="/TelUtiles"
            style={styles.navItem_login}
            underlayColor='#f0f4f7'>
            <Image source={require('./img/icono-tel.png')} style={{width:70, height:70,margin:10}} />
        </Link>
      </View>

      <Route path="/public" component={Public}/>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/TelUtiles" component={TelUtiles}/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected}/>


    </View>
  </NativeRouter>


)

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true
    setTimeout(cb, 100) // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    this.isAuthenticated = false
    setTimeout(cb, 100)
  }
}

const AuthButton = withRouter(({ history }) => (
  fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome!</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight style={styles.btn} underlayColor='#f0f4f7' onPress={() => {
        fakeAuth.signout(() => history.push('/'))
      }}><Text>Sign out</Text></TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  ) : (
    <Text>You are not logged in.</Text>
  )
))

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)

const Public = () => <Text style={styles.header}>Public</Text>
const Protected = () => <Text style={styles.header}>Protected</Text>

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    redirectToReferrer: false
  }

  login = () => {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
      this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } }
    const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state

    if (redirectToReferrer) {
      return (
        <Redirect to={from}/>
      )
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</Text>

        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.btn} underlayColor='#f0f4f7' onPress={this.login}>
          <Text>Log in</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default AuthExample
```

Comment: Are you using multiple `NativeRouter` components? Try just using one single `NativeRouter` at the top of your app.

Comment: Nope, the NativeRouter is just in the parent component

Comment: Could you include the entire component that has your routing logic in it in the question?

Comment: there you go. thanks. i had to put that dummy text because it didn't let me add the code :S

Comment: Have you tried wrapping all your `Route` components in a [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/api/Switch) component?

Comment: i've just done that and still the same...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"the view is not being replaced with the linked one"`? If you are on `/login` and follow the link to `/TelUtiles`, `TelUtiles` will be rendered on top of `Login`?

Comment: right, it renders /TelUtiles over what AuthExample() renders.

Comment: https://ibb.co/nuXgid

Comment: Where it says "Números utiles:" is the linked component

Comment: Isn't that the intended behavior? You render your `Route` components inside of the `AuthExample`. The active `Route` will just be replaced with the `component` given to it. Isn't it a styling issue if they overlap? Sorry, I don't think I can help.

Comment: The behaviour i'm looking for is to navigate to the linked component. Now the component that links is not being replaced, "it stays" in the screen and the linked component displays below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to render the content of `AuthExample` on a certain route, you could break that out into a separate component and render that on the index route `/` and also use a `Switch` component to make sure that only one of the `Route` components in the `Switch` are used at once.

**Example**

```
const Main = () => (
  <View>
    <View style={styles.welcomeMsg}>
      <Text style={styles.welcomeMsg_textTop}>¡Bienvenido a nuestra</Text>
      <Text style={styles.welcomeMsg_textBottom}>familia mascotera!</Text>
      <View style={styles.container_input_dni}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="DNI:"
          placeholderTextColor="#E3A141"
          underlineColorAndroid="#E3A141"
          style={styles.input_dni}
        />
      </View>
      <Link
        to="/protected"
        style={styles.navItem_login}
        underlayColor="#f0f4f7"
      >
        <Text style={styles.navItem_login_text}>Protected Page</Text>
      </Link>
    </View>
    <AuthButton />
    <View style={styles.nav}>
      <Link to="/public" style={styles.navItem} underlayColor="#f0f4f7">
        <Text>Public Page</Text>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/protected" style={styles.navItem} underlayColor="#f0f4f7">
        <Text>Protected Page</Text>
      </Link>
      <Link
        to="/TelUtiles"
        style={styles.navItem_login}
        underlayColor="#f0f4f7"
      >
        <Image
          source={require("./img/icono-tel.png")}
          style={{ width: 70, height: 70, margin: 10 }}
        />
      </Link>
    </View>
  </View>
);

const AuthExample = () => (
  <NativeRouter>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container_logo}>
        <Image
          source={require("./img/logo-main.png")}
          style={styles.logo_img}
        />
      </View>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/public" component={Public} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/TelUtiles" component={TelUtiles} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected} />
      </Switch>
    </View>
  </NativeRouter>
);
```

Comment: Thank you!!!. Now the problem is when i hit the back arrow from the device the app minimize and doesn't return to the previous route, am i missing something else?

Comment: @Guille If you want to use the back button for the navigation, you must use the [`BackButton`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/api/BackButton) component as first child to your `NativeRouter` component.

Comment: Thanks again!!, i really appreciate your help :D

Comment: Hi @Tholle, how should i manage a "go back" button?, i mean how can i get the previous visited screen?. Thanks!